# Single post comment template not working

Tags: single

I cant get the comments template to show up in my single-events.php

This is my code

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'events' ); ?>
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

If I put the comments template in my events template (events.php), it will show up but it doesnt work on the single posts.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Here's 2 solutions i tested:

Try adding support for comments in your custom post type code

```
'supports' => array(  'comments' ),
```

You could also use `add_post_type_support`

```
add_action('init', 'wpsites_comments');
function wpsites_comments() {
    add_post_type_support( 'events', 'comments' );
}
```

[Code Source](http://wpsites.net/web-design/add-support-for-comments-on-single-custom-post-type-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
comments_template('/single-comment.php');
```

`single-comment.php` is the file that contains all the content from `comment.php`.
You can later edit this (`single-comment.php`) file.